# Secure Auth/Encryption Smart Keyboard

Tags: kernel, keyboard, encryption, udev

Due to the nature of a personal subnet (hardened on the outside, trusting/naive on the inside) I'm starting a project within my network (routed by a Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop with OpenVPN public/local traffic encryption) in which I am aiming for completely paranoid and possibly excessive security to prevent an internal breach (malware installed on a LAN client infecting subnet).

Among countless other projects I'm about to engage in is a "Smart Keyboard." I am aiming to prevent certain HID based attacks such as hardware keyloggers and BadUSB exploit. In order to do this I am modifying a standard keyboard, gutting the driver board and installing a micro-controller such as a Teensy to read input voltage, authenticate to computer using rsa/ecdsa or another asymmetric cipher, and encrypt keystrokes in AES with a rolling code synchronized with the computer to avoid the potential for a replay attack.

The hardware side seems simple enough, as does encryption and decryption of data. The part where I need help is a lack of understanding in how HID devices communicate with a system, namely Ubuntu (what kind of data can be read by a standard HID device?) as well as how to attach a process to handle decryption of data.

I have read into /etc/udev/ some and it seems like the execution of scripts is not typically meant for long running applications such as this. How would I go about executing a 'handler' for the keyboard and would this script exclusively receive the data, or would it just be reading stdin since it is a userspace script and HID devices are handled by the kernel?

Lastly, would I be better off to open a 'channel' to the Teensy rather than handling it as an HID device? I am reluctant to do this because this would make the keyboard unusable during boot.

I'm not necessarily looking for direct answers, but possibly resources for study. I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Regards,
Lisenby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I'm not an expert, AFAIK, the best is to make a new driver (kernel module) for your new encrypted keyboard.

  Here is project that is small and easy to understand.

  > Long Name: Linux Microdia Keyboard Chipset Driver
  >    Short Name: `aziokbd`
  >    Author: Colin Svingen (Swoogan)
  >    Project Home: https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd

  It is using DKMS, so no need for Linux kernel rebuild.
- I lack knowledge about encryption tools so I can't help on how to handle the encrypted data stream.
- `udev` in short words, it's daemon part of `systemd`. It helps making dynamic setup/configuration and run customized scripts whenever conditions match either when a device node created, changed or removed from the kernel tree. (`/sys` is  a Virtual FS that show same tree currently in the kernel).

  It will help you but it's not what you are looking for.
- Another option, using user-space driver/daemon. In this case, you have to access the USB device using `libusb`. Same way as `xboxdrv` (driver for xbox controller) and `xsane` (tool for scanners).